# Cannot find the proper typing for a certain kind of varargs function

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typing

Please have a look at the following little demo:

- Function `f` should accept ONE pair of the form ['stringX', 'stringXstringX'] (-> this is working)
- But function `g` should accept A VARIABLE NUMBER of pairs of this pattern.
  How do I have to type function `g` to make this happen?

```js
function f<T extends string, U extends `${T}${T}`>(arg: [T, U]) {}
function g(...args: ???[]) {} // what's the right type here (-> ???)?

f(['a', 'aa']) // ok
f(['a', 'ab']) // error as expected

g(
  ['a', 'aa'], // should be okay
  ['b', 'bb'], // should be okay
  ['c', 'ab']  // should result in a compile error!!!
)
```

» [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMAPAFUQUwB5U2AEwGdEioAnGMAcwBpEBVLXfYxAAwBIBvNAXx792APgAUAQ3LUAXIgDaaegwC6ASkTc+AKFCRYCRNVEA6U5OpFZAfhty1GvogD0TxAHcAFuKgByElA9MREpqDyhEKABPAAcgwPIg0QBaYUQbK1UrLR1ROR9xH3p8gvsXRDgAaxy8gqLxACMfUtdMcnI4ckRxEhxY6EwCbKMtRHl8wsRipvoyog84EAAbAkR6oMrxSJGxxqL6xuUZ1zmF5dX1is3tvIgJ-IPR2fmllYSiJfCqLsQIOABbaIwRZBVrtcgAQkhWlU2SAA)

[Edit] Of course I can change function `g` to have n optional arguments combined with 2*n type parameters, but this is not the solution I am looking for.

[Edit] By the way: If function `g` would accept ONE ARRAY of those tuples instead of varargs and behave accordingly that would also be a useful solution, but I guess it's the same problem.

[Edit] Making `g` a single-argument function of the following form will work but is syntactically not very nice:

```js
// expected error at the 'ab'
g(['a', 'aa'])(['b', 'bb'])(['c', 'ab'])
```

See [DEMO](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=8&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAcwDwBVEFMAeUtgAmAzosVAE4xjIA0AqtngSYgAYAkA3ugL7d82APgAUAQwrIAXIgDa6WonoBdAJSIuAKESIKWKCApJkm3pu0B6C0wAOWaFkLYKFOBUQAje2JDEsiOGBEKAALfwByMQ9wxDEoYLDsIk1kEVlI8MVIsXC1NPDorI9ovPSITMRIktVzIA)

Comment: For `f` you don't need that second type parameter. As for `g`, I don't believe there is a way to type that for a truly arbitrary number of arguments.

Comment: Ingo, just out of interest: How would I get rid of the second type parameter as you've mentioned? This demo here is at least not working:  [DEMO](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMAPAFUQUwB5U2AEwGdEioAnGMAcwD4AKAQ3OoC5EBtNAGkQAMAJAG80AX2Fi+AXQCUiIaIBQi4PQ4ByRut6atsxAHoDiOAGsVazdsTrsAT3X6jiFAFpEEEOXL4oAGztEMDgsbzhyRAALTB8AQnjlRSA)

Comment: Would relaxing the requirement to, say, 6 parameters max be possible? I tried and failed

Comment: @paroxyzm If it's not "Change function g to have n optional arguments combined with 2*n type parameters" like written in my '[Edit]' comment above ... every alternative solution is also welcome

Comment: Would something like this satisfy you? shorturl.at/hnFMP

Comment: @paroxyzm Thanks a lot for the solution using function overriding. But as in my real use case there will easily be a dozen or more arguments this is unfortunately not practical for my use case. I think I'll have to go with this `g(..)(..)(..)(..)(..)` solution as mentioned in my third "Edit" comment above.

Comment: Sure, this was a very interesting question, and a solution is pretty as well (with currying). Thanks!

Comment: Does [this code](https://tsplay.dev/m05nxW) work for you?  If so I could write up an answer.  If not, please [edit] the question code to show unsatisfied use cases.

Comment: These are by far the most interesting five lines of code that I've seen for a long time :-) ... I do not know how ;-), but it seems to do exactly what have been the requirements. Thank you very much, looking forward to your full answer.

Comment: Okay I'll write up an answer when I get a chance.  (Please @-mention me like "@jcalz" if you need me to see a comment; for some reason without that I might not get a notification... I just happened to see [yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70058473/typescript-cannot-find-the-proper-typing-for-a-certain-kind-of-varargs-functi#comment123846472_70058473) but did not get a notification for it)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My approach here would look like this:

```
function g<T extends string[]>(...args: { [I in keyof T]:
  [T[I], NoInfer<Dupe<T[I]>>]
}) { }

type Dupe<T> = T extends string ? `${T}${T}` : never;

type NoInfer<T> = [T][T extends any ? 0 : never];
```

The idea is that `g()` is [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in the type parameter `T[]`, a [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) consisting of just the string [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) from the first element of each pair of strings from `args`.  So if you call `g(["a", "aa"], ["b", "bb"], ["c", "cc"])`, then `T` should be the tuple type `["a", "b", "c"]`.

The type of `args` can then be represented in terms of `T` by a [mapped tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays).  For each numeric index `I` from the `T` tuple, the corresponding element of `args` should have a type like `[T[I], Dupe<T[I]>]`, where `Dupe<T>` concatenates strings to themselves in the desired way.  So if `T` is `["z", "y"]`, then the type of `args` should be `[["z", "zz"], ["y", "yy"]]`.

The goal here is that the compiler should see a call like `g(["x", "xx"], ["y", "oops"])` and [infer `T` from the type of `args`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#inference-from-mapped-types) to be `["x", "y"]`, and then check against the type of `args` and notice that while `["x", "xx"]` is fine, `["y", "oops"]` does not match the expected `["y", "yy"]` and thus there is an error.

That's the basic approach, but there are some issues we need to work around.

---

First, there is an open issue at [microsoft/TypeScript#27995](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27995) that causes the compiler to fail to recognize that `T[I]` will definitely be a `string` inside the mapped tuple type `{[I in keyof T]: [T[I], Dupe<T[I]>]}`.  Even though a mapped tuple type creates another tuple type, the compiler thinks that `I` might be some other key of `any[]` like `"map"` or `"length"` and therefore `T[I]` could be a function type or `number`, etc.

And so if we had defined `Dupe<T>` like

```
type Dupe<T extends string> = `${T}${T}`;
```

there would be a problem where `Dupe<T[I]>` would cause an error.  In order to circumvent that problem, I have defined `Dupe<T>` so that it does not require that `T` is a `string`.  Instead, it just uses a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) to say "*if* `T` is a `string`, *then* `Dupe<T>` will be `` `${T}${T}` ``":

```
type Dupe<T> = T extends string ? `${T}${T}` : never;
```

So that takes care of that problem.

---

The next problem is that to infer `T` from a value of type `{[I in keyof T]: [T[I], Dupe<T[I]>]}`, the compiler is free to look both at the first element of each `args` pair (`T[I]`), as well as the second element (`Dupe<T[I]>`).  Each mention of `T[I]` in that type is an *inference site* for `T[I]`. We want the compiler only to look at the first element of each pair when inferring `T`, and to just *check* the second element.  Unfortunately, if you leave it like this, the compiler tries to use both and gets confused.

That is, when inferring `T` from `[["y", "zz"]]`, the compiler will match `"y"` agains `T[I]` and `"zz"` against `Dupe<T[I]>`, and it ends up inferring the [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) `["y" | "z"]` for `T`.  That's quite clever, actually, since if `T` really were `["y" | "z"]`, then the type of `args` would be of type `["y" | "z", "yy" | "zz"]`, and the value `["y", "zz"]` matches it.  Nice! Except you want to *reject* `[["y", "zz"]]`.

So we need some way to tell the compiler *not* to use the second element of each pair to infer `T`.  There is an open issue at [microsoft/TypeScript#14829](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14829) which asks for some support for
"non-inferential type parameter usage" of the form `NoInfer<T>`.  A type like `NoInfer<T>` would eventually evaluate to `T`, but would block the compiler from trying to infer `T` from it.  And so we'd write `{[I in keyof T]: [T[I], NoInfer<Dupe<T[I]>>]}`.

There's no native or official `NoInfer<T>` type in TypeScript, but there are some implementations which work in some circumstances.  I tend to use [this version](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14829#issuecomment-504042546) or something like it to take advantage of the compiler's tendency to *defer* evaluation of unresolved conditional types:

```
type NoInfer<T> = [T][T extends any ? 0 : never];
```

If you put some specific type in for `T`, this will evaluate to `T` (e.g., `NoInfer<string>` is `[string][string extends any ? 0 : never]` which is `[string][0]` which is `string`), but when `T` is an unspecified generic type, the compiler leaves it unevaluated and does not eagerly replace it with `T`.  So `NoInfer<T>` is opaque to the compiler when `T` is some generic type parameter, and we can use it to block type inference.

---

So there's the explanation (whew!).  Let's make sure it works:

```
g(
  ['a', 'aa'], // okay
  ['b', 'bb'], // okay
  ['c', 'dd']  // error!
  // -> ~~~~
  // Type '"dd"' is not assignable to type '"cc"'. (2322)
)
```

Looks good!  The compiler is happy with `["a", "aa"]` and `["b", "bb"]` but balks at `["c", "dd"]` with a nice error message about how it expected `"cc"` but got `"dd"` instead.

---

This answers the question as asked.  But do note that the typing for `g()` will only really be useful for *callers* of `g()` who do so with *specific* and *literal* strings passed in.  As soon as someone calls `g()` with unresolved *generic* strings (say inside the body of some generic function), or as soon as you try to inspect `T` or `args` inside the body of the implementation of `g()`, you will find that the compiler cannot really understand the implications.  In those cases you'll be better off widening to something like `[string, string][]` or the like and just being careful.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAcgewJIDsBmUBOAeAKgPhgF4YBtXAXXJigA8QoUATAZxgEMUwYB+GABhgAuGCigA3LBQDcwUJFgARAK7Q8hErhr1GrGCxCYAligDmvGAAMAJAG9cAXzuPLw0RKyzgaZSgDGIEYIKDCmeNoMzGwGxmakFPgAFAB0qeyYpiwitmRIMCYwANZQYAhoMJRCwDBkuKRIFAA08MjoWNgqanUN+PgUwA4AlDA5DnKmidVkAOTs082zc00wAPQrMAiF7GBTpNMARvMwB4fLaxtbOzV7fkfTTEzTFDXnWJgImACEU+cAtIQAPyBAJ+61wCmOACIHpDpvk2CgECAOCwWEZTCh2PsADawEAIGDgaBQvx+WHJGCJABMAGYqVTBsBGcAgA)